# "Distribution worker" vs. "distributed worker"

Tags: word-choice, nouns, adjectives

I cannot differentiate the meanings of the two words. Could you please clarify?

In general, when should I use a noun (*distribution*) or an adjective (*distributed*) for verbs similar to *distribute*, like *organize, create*?

Comment: Have you heard about our ELL Q&A? http://ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Distributed worker* doesn't make a great deal of sense generally (although there may be some specific usage where it does), so let's change that noun to one which can easily be used in both phrases.

> Distribution work
>   Distributed work

*Distribution* is an attributive noun, a noun used as an adjective to describe *work*. It means that the work is involved with distribution. The phrase doesn't say what is being distributed.

*Distributed* is a participle. While it too describes *work*, it describes **what has been done** to the work: it is **the work** which has been shared around, or distributed among a number of recipients.

The same constructions can be applied to other things, where an attributive noun describes the principal noun, and a participle describes what has been done to it:

> Paint brush, a brush used for paint
>   Painted brush, a brush which has been painted
>
> Paper ceiling, a ceiling made of paper
>   Papered ceiling, a ceiling covered with paper
>
> Organization work, work to do with the organization [of something]
>   Organized work, work which has been organized into a particular pattern or structure
>
> Creation work, work to do with creating something
>   Created work, something (like an artwork) which has been created

Thus a *distributed worker* is a **worker who has been shared out**. I can't imagine that the recipients of that worker would be very happy with being given body parts! One might have a *distributed ‘worker process’* in computing, perhaps.

Comment: @ToanNguyen "distributed workerS" (plural) would make sense, it means you have many workers in different places. But "distributed worker" (single) doesn't make sense - because it would be one worker in many places (unless you had a nasty accident with a saw)

Comment: Hello there, Can you explain using V-ing as adjective like "distributing worker" vs "distribution worker"

Comment: A *distributing worker* isn't a very common way of putting it. However a participle can behave as an adjective: "He is distributing [the mail]" -- it has a similar function to the word *hairy* in "He is hairy". Just as you can have a hairy worker, so you can have a distributing worker.

Answer (score 3):

As the others have mentioned, a `distribution worker` is someone involved in, ahem, distribution, such as a lorry driver, whilst a `distributed worker` in the singular sense doesn't make sense, however `distributed workers` plural does and would imply a number of different workers spread across different locations.

`Distribution workers` could be considered `distributed workers` as they are all out doing they're deliveries in different places.

Answer (score 2):

'Distribution worker' means someone who works in that area. 'Distributed' is the past tense, meaning something (like papers) has been handed out to people. 
"Distributed worker' does not exist.

Comment: *worker* is cited here only as an example. The question clearly relates to noun vs. adj. use.

Answer (score 0):

A *distribution network* is a network that allows the distribution of your products.

The internet is a *distributed network* as the resources it uses are distributed over many networks.